# Write bash script to output results of commands on remote device in text file on local device

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, network-programming

I'm looking at writing a bash script to run a bunch of commands to multiple devices and I want to output the results of each command into a text file on the local device.

So far this is about all I have:

```
#!bin/bash


devices={host1 host2}

commands={command1;command2;command3}

if i in ${devices}; do
echo "Working on host: ${i}"
ssh ${i} ${commands} > ${i}_output.txt
echo "====================================================================="
done
```

Comment: You need a loop. and arrays, or if you prefer brace expansion that is not the syntax.  paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: I don't understand your code. You are calling a program named `i` with the three parameters `in`, `{host1` and `host2}`. I would expect that you see an error message there; something like _command not found_. Another question: Do your remote commands really consist of a single word only, i.e. _command2_ ?

Comment: first of all it's "for" not "if",  and since you have more than 1 command than you have to do another for loop inside the first.